# Centre alignment in CKEditor 4.10 toolbar is disabled when selecting image inserted in the editor

Tags: image, ckeditor, alignment

I am using CKEditor version 4.10 in an mail delivery system project for composing emails. I have added **justify plugin** to get the *justify tools* in the toolbar. Since this is an email composing, user may want to align the contents(**including images inserted**) as *Left, Right, Centre* etc. But even though I can choose Left and Right align buttons in the toolbar after selecting the image, I cannot choose centre align button because it is disabled. Does anyone know how can I enable the centre align button on selecting the images inserted in the editor and can able to align the same in centre too ?

Answer (score 0):

Click right on image then click Image properties option, when page open then click advance Tab and in the style field delete `float:right;` Or `float:left;` and just type `display:block;margin:auto;` . Then you can see image set center on page.